# NotifyOSD notification when I change keyboard layout in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-12.04, notify-osd

I would like to have a NotifyOSD notification appear whenever I change keyboard layouts. Does anybody know how I can implement this feature?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I think is to make your own script to change layout, and make that script to notify you too.
Some methods are listed here https://askubuntu.com/questions/92751/create-my-own-keyboard-input-layout

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.